# Find the value of the constants given the $n$th term of a sequence, the limit and the first two terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

The $n$th term of the sequence is $u_n$. The sequence is defined by
$$u_{n+1}=pu_n+q$$
$p$ and $q$ are constants. The first two terms of the sequence are given by
$$u_1=60$$
$$u_2=48$$
The limit of $u_n$ as $n$ tends to infinity is $12$.

Find the value of $p$ and $q$.

$$u_2=pu_1+q$$
$$48=p60+q$$next
$$\infty=\infty+1$$
$$u_{\infty}=12$$
therefore
$$u_{\infty+1}=pu_\infty+q$$
$$12=p12+q$$

Then solve. Is this right? Regards Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's right! But I think you can be more rigourious about using limits and saying that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\,u_{n+1}=f(u_n)$ where $f(x)=px+q$ which is a **continuous** function in $\mathbb{R}$. Since $\{u_n\}$ converges and its limit is $12$ therefore $f(12)=12\Rightarrow 12p+q=12$